# How to pass Params to PDO prepare statement

Tags: php, pdo

I m new to PHP PDO and I want to pass param to a query in prepare statement but i have been failed again and again although it is working fine in mysqli statements but here it is not showing me records not showing any error..problem is with passing the params   please some one guide me ...

**Here is my code..**

```
if($_GET['title']!="" && isset($_GET['cities']) && isset($_GET['categories'])){

    $title = trim($_GET['title']);
    $cities = $_GET['cities'];
    $categories = $_GET['categories'];
    foreach($cities as $city) {
      $recordcities .= $city."|";
    }
    foreach($categories as $category){
      $recordCat .= $category."|";
    }

    $select = $pdo->prepare("select * from selectcities WHERE CONCAT(',', `cities`, ',') REGEXP ',(:cities),' and CONCAT(',', `category`, ',') REGEXP ',(:categories),' ");
    $select->bindParam(':cities',$recordCities,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $select->bindParam(':categories',$recordCat,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $select->execute();
    echo $select->rowCount();
    while($result = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
       //echo $result['Title'].'<br>';
       print_r($result);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to make the bind variables contain any extra markup rather than try and include it in the SQL, so your bind becomes `',('.$recordCities.'),'` and the SQL is just `REGEXP :cities`...

```
$select = $pdo->prepare("select * from selectcities 
            WHERE CONCAT(',', `cities`, ',') REGEXP :cities 
              and CONCAT(',', `category`, ',') REGEXP :categories ");
$recordCities = ',('.$recordCities.'),';
$recordCat = ',('.$recordCat.'),';
$select->bindParam(':cities',$recordCities,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$select->bindParam(':categories',$recordCat,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: $select = $pdo->prepare("select * from selectcities
            WHERE CONCAT(',', `cities`, ',') REGEXP ?
              and CONCAT(',', `category`, ',') REGEXP ? ");
$params = array(',('.$recordcities.'),',',('.$recordCat.'),');
    $select->execute($params);

now it working like this but now with bindParam

Comment: Sorry - the values have to be changed before the call to  `bindParam` as they are passed by reference (the ` mixed &$variable` & means they have to be a variable and not a value) - corrected answer